# url captured regex (\w+) not matching certain urls

Tags: python, regex, django

The two lines of the urls.py config file for `my_app` are shown below. They're almost the same, only the second has a uuid4 appended to it

```
# preview views to allow us to preview stuff
url(r'^(?P<hash>\w+)/preview/$', Start.as_view(), {'preview':True}, name='preview'),
url(r'^(?P<hash>\w+)/preview/(?P<uuid>[a-f0-9]{8}-?[a-f0-9]{4}-?4[a-f0-9]{3}-?[89ab][a-f0-9]{3}-?[a-f0-9]{12})/$', PreviewController.as_view(), name='previewcontroller'),
```

The following urls work without error:

- http://example.com/my_app/2307099758/preview/
- http://example.com/my_app/2660962971/preview/
- http://example.com/my_app/475966143/preview/

The following urls yield the below error (all `hash` values are valid, but that shouldn't affect the url resolution):

- http://example.com/my_app/841211121/preview/
- http://example.com/my_app/2398929036/preview/

> Internal Server Error: /my_app/841211121/preview/
>
> NoReverseMatch at /my_app/841211121/preview/ Reverse for
>   ‘previewcontroller’ with arguments ‘()’ and keyword arguments
>   ‘{'uuid’: None, ‘hash’: ‘841211121'}’ not found. 1 pattern(s)
>   tried:
>   ['my_app/(?P\w+)/preview/(?P[a-f0-9]{8}-?[a-f0-9]{4}-?4[a-f0-9]{3}-?[89ab][a-f0-9]{3}-?[a-f0-9]{12})/$']
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL:
>   http://example.com/my_app/841211121/preview/ 
>   Django Version: 1.10...

Regex101.com says that the url should match (with escaped slashes, of course). Why on earth are the second group of urls not matching the `preview` url, and what is provoking the url resolver to attempt to match them to `previewcontroller` when there is no `uuid` string appended to the url?

Comment: The problem is in your `Start` view or template, which you haven't shown. It looks like a `reverse()` call or `{% url %}` template tag is failing.

Comment: Ah thanks - I'll go and look there and report back with what I find.

Comment: Yes; the template was incorrectly passed a context variable url link that matched `previewcontroller` by coincidence. If you paste that in I'll accept the answer. Thanks enormously Alasdair!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Django is correctly resolving the `/my_app/841211121/preview/` and running the correct view.

The problem is occurring when Django runs the `Start` view. It looks like a `reverse()` call or `{% url %}` template tag is failing.